# Congratulations and thanks to everyone on graduating to a full stackexchange site

Tags: discussion

Our Q and A site for Korean language was recently [upgraded from a beta site to a full site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta/) by stackexchange

I would like to thank everyone who has participated on our site, by following the site from the time it was proposed in Area51 almost 7 years ago, up to today when the site has formally launched

Our site's journey is in fact longer than this, as it had been proposed in Area51 before, stayed in definition stage for around 2 years but was ultimately deleted due to lack of followers. A lot of the community members who were around during the previous Area51 definition followed this version of the site, and I can recognize some usernames that have been active up to this day. I want to thank you all for sticking around this long. A special shoutout to our community member [Earthliŋ](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/56/earthli%C5%8B) who [provided the final impetus](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/four-more-people-for-the-korean-language-proposal) to bring the site into the commitment phase in Area51, when it looked like the site was almost doomed during definition, and also helped in promoting it by creating a [community ad](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/community-promotion-ads-2015/3299#3299)

As far as the site usage goes I don't think any of us will notice any difference. The site will still work as before, only the "beta" label from the site logo (top left) is now removed. When our site first went into public beta, I was fearing whether it would be shut down at some point, since our site was (and still is) relatively small with less activity ([See the site metrics in Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language)). However, with our community effort we have managed to come this far, and now that this is a "full" site, I am hoping we will be around for much longer

If we google for any information on Korean language (help with grammar, word/phrase/sentence comprehension, translation, etc), there are usually a lot of results, many of which usually contain the correct answer. However, all the information is scattered all over the place, on different sites, blogs, "yahoo answers" type Q and A sites and even tumbler posts. This had been one of my motivations for proposing the latest version of the site's Area51 beta, even though the previous one failed. I have always felt that a need for a centralized question and answer site for Korean language is there, just that any particular site on the internet doesn't have enough momentum to grow into one. I think with our combined effort we can fill this space, as we have a good community here with some very expert level users

Again I would like to thank all the users for your participation and support, the stackexchange team for finally promoting our site, and everyone who has been following this site from the previous version of it's Area51 beta

Comment: Thank you to all the users of our community. This site is your site and is a reflection of a significant amount of joint work.