# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2023

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

**Summary**: Korean Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **October 24, 2023**, as your “graduation” election as a result of [having lost your beta label a while back](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/149) and a recent mod removal due to inactivity.

The timeline:

- On October 17, 2023, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on October 24, 2023, users can [nominate themselves](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On October 31, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods), and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on November 8, 2023 (or November 15, 2023, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.